# Cordova exec call to Observable

Tags: angular, cordova, rxjs, observable, ionic3

I am trying to get free space on the phone and pass it to Ionic. Cordova does the job, but I have trouble converting it into an Observable. Here is a service I created.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class PhoneService {

    getFreeSpace() {
        return Observable.from(
            window['cordova'].exec(
                result => { return result},
                error => { return error},
                'File',
                'getFreeDiskSpace',
                [])
        )
    }

}
```

When I call it, the cordova.exec runs properly and `result` is retrieved. However I can only get it within the call. The Observable is not returned, I get `undefined` instead:

```
this.getFreeSpace = this.phoneService.getFreeSpace()
                    .subscribe(result => { console.log(result) });
```

The result is:

```
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not observable
```

Apparently this is not how I am supposed to do it. Anyone smarter than me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cordova API you are using doesn't appear to return a promise, but instead is callback-based.  You cannot use `Observable.from()` for this.  You'll have to use `Observable.create`:

```
getFreeSpace() {
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    window['cordova'].exec(
      result => { observer.next(result); observer.complete(); },
      error => observer.error(result),
      'File',
      'getFreeDiskSpace',
      []);
  });
}
```

Comment: Yay! Thanks. The more you know.